Optimizing Form Rendering with Multiple Tabs and Dynamic Form Items
I want to structure a form effectively. My goal is to create a page with five tabs, each containing 10 unique form items with different types, such as text, number, and select fields. I've built the structure by setting up a Tab and TabContent area, displaying the corresponding TabContent based on the active tab. Each tab's 10 form items are defined in constants as objects with types, allowing the form component to render the appropriate form item based on the type. The layout displays correctly, but the rendering speed is slow. How can I improve the performance? Below is a partial code example showing the relevant sections. I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions for optimization.
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import {
  Tabs as UITabs,
  Tab as UITab,
  TabContent as UITabContent,
  FormInput,
  FormSelect,
  FormInputNumber,
} from 'your-ui-library';

const FORM_LIST = [
  {
    id: 0,
    key: 'school',
    title: 'School',
    fieldsList: SCHOOL_FIELDS,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    key: 'college',
    title: 'College',
    fieldsList: COLLEGE_FIELDS,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    key: 'university',
    title: 'University',
    fieldsList: UNIVERSITY_FIELDS,
  },
];

export const UNIVERSITY_FIELDS = [
  {
    type: 'select',
    name: '1',
    label: 'Region',
    description: 'test',
    options: [
      { label: 'Korea', value: 'korean' },
      { label: 'India', value: 'india' },
    ],
    validationRules: { required: 'Role selection is required' },
  },
  {
    type: 'inputNumber',
    name: '2',
    label: 'Minimum Letters',
    validationRules: { required: 'Number is required' },
  },
];

// Tabs Component
const Tabs = ({ tabs, activeTab, onTabChange }) => {
  return (
    <UITabs orientation="vertical" onChangeTab={(newTab) => onTabChange(newTab)} outline>
      {tabs.map((tab) => (
        <UITab key={tab.id} id={tab.id} label={tab.title}>
          {tab.title}
        </UITab>
      ))}
    </UITabs>
  );
};

// TabContent Component
const TabContent = ({ activeTab, tabs }) => {
  const content = useMemo(() => {
    return tabs
      .filter((tab) => tab.id === activeTab)
      .map((tab) => (
        <UITabContent key={tab.id} value={tab.id} activeTabNum={activeTab}>
          <FieldRenderContent fields={tab.fieldsList} />
        </UITabContent>
      ));
  }, [activeTab, tabs]);

  return <>{content}</>;
};

// FieldRenderer Component
const FieldRenderer = ({ field }) => {
  switch (field.type) {
    case 'input':
      return (
        <FormInput
          name={field.name}
          label={field.label}
          description={field.description}
          validationRules={field.validationRules}
        />
      );
    case 'select':
      return (
        <FormSelect
          name={field.name}
          label={field.label}
          options={field.options}
          description={field.description}
          isClearable={true}
          validationRules={field.validationRules}
        />
      );
    case 'inputNumber':
      return <FormInputNumber name={field.name} label={field.label} validationRules={field.validationRules} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

// FieldRenderContent Component
const FieldRenderContent = ({ fields }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((field) => (
        <FieldRenderer key={field.name} field={field} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

// Main Component
const FormPage = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      {/* Tabs */}
      <div style={{ marginRight: '16px' }}>
        <Tabs tabs={FORM_LIST} activeTab={activeTab} onTabChange={setActiveTab} />
      </div>

      {/* Tab Content */}
      <div>
        <TabContent activeTab={activeTab} tabs={FORM_LIST} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormPage;



this should not be slow, you don't even use state for fields' data. I suggest to use : https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html, to check

The answer contains all possible (to my knowledge) optimizations without changing the code structure, which is mostly about the usage of memo and useCallback. Some of the changes are subtle and won't largely affect the performance, while the lazy load of tabs should drastically improve the performance overall.
Possible Optimizations

Lazy Loading for Tab Content: Render only the active tab’s form items
to avoid unnecessary re-renders of all tabs. Currently, useMemo
creates the content array for all tabs, even those not active. Use
conditional rendering to display only the active tab.
Memoize Field Components: Avoid re-rendering field components
unnecessarily. Memoize FieldRenderer and FieldRenderContent to
prevent them from re-rendering unless the field data itself changes
Avoiding Inline Functions: Move the handleTabChange function outside
of the JSX to avoid re-creating it on every render.
useCallback method: Memoizes callback functions to prevent re-creation on every render, which can cause child components to re-render if passed as props.

Complete example:
import React, { useState, useMemo, memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  Tabs as UITabs,
  Tab as UITab,
  TabContent as UITabContent,
  FormInput,
  FormSelect,
  FormInputNumber,
} from 'your-ui-library';

// Constant for Form Fields
const FORM_LIST = [
  {
    id: 0,
    key: 'school',
    title: 'School',
    fieldsList: SCHOOL_FIELDS,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    key: 'college',
    title: 'College',
    fieldsList: COLLEGE_FIELDS,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    key: 'university',
    title: 'University',
    fieldsList: UNIVERSITY_FIELDS,
  },
];

export const UNIVERSITY_FIELDS = [
  {
    type: 'select',
    name: '1',
    label: 'Region',
    description: 'test',
    options: [
      { label: 'Korea', value: 'korean' },
      { label: 'India', value: 'india' },
    ],
    validationRules: { required: 'Role selection is required' },
  },
  {
    type: 'inputNumber',
    name: '2',
    label: 'Minimum Letters',
    validationRules: { required: 'Number is required' },
  },
];

// Tabs Component (Memoized)
const Tabs = memo(({ tabs, activeTab, onTabChange }) => {
  return (
    <UITabs orientation="vertical" onChangeTab={onTabChange} outline>
      {tabs.map((tab) => (
        <UITab key={tab.id} id={tab.id} label={tab.title}>
          {tab.title}
        </UITab>
      ))}
    </UITabs>
  );
});

// TabContent Component with Lazy Loading
const TabContent = ({ activeTab, tabs }) => {
  const activeTabContent = useMemo(() => tabs.find((tab) => tab.id === activeTab), [activeTab, tabs]);

  return (
    <UITabContent key={activeTabContent.id} value={activeTabContent.id}>
      <FieldRenderContent fields={activeTabContent.fieldsList} />
    </UITabContent>
  );
};

// FieldRenderer Component (Memoized)
const FieldRenderer = memo(({ field }) => {
  switch (field.type) {
    case 'input':
      return (
        <FormInput
          name={field.name}
          label={field.label}
          description={field.description}
          validationRules={field.validationRules}
        />
      );
    case 'select':
      return (
        <FormSelect
          name={field.name}
          label={field.label}
          options={field.options}
          description={field.description}
          isClearable={true}
          validationRules={field.validationRules}
        />
      );
    case 'inputNumber':
      return (
        <FormInputNumber
          name={field.name}
          label={field.label}
          validationRules={field.validationRules}
        />
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
});

// FieldRenderContent Component (Memoized)
const FieldRenderContent = memo(({ fields }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {fields.map((field) => (
        <FieldRenderer key={field.name} field={field} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
});

// Main FormPage Component
const FormPage = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

  const handleTabChange = useCallback((newTab) => {
    setActiveTab(newTab);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      {/* Tabs */}
      <div style={{ marginRight: '16px' }}>
        <Tabs tabs={FORM_LIST} activeTab={activeTab} onTabChange={handleTabChange} />
      </div>

      {/* Tab Content */}
      <div>
        <TabContent activeTab={activeTab} tabs={FORM_LIST} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormPage;

